# simpler implementation of this string splitting loop

Tags: python

I have a function that receives a string that is dot delimited. I want to loop through this value building it up and running some code for each level. Here is an implementation:

```
def example(name):
    module = []
    for i in name.split('.'):
        module.append(i)
        print '.'.join(module)
        #do some stuff here
```

**output**

```
>>> example('a.b.c.d')
a
a.b
a.b.c
a.b.c.d
```

But it feels very long winded. I'm looking for a simpler, cleaner or shorter implementation.

Comment: For general `#do some stuff here`, I think this is the right approach.

Comment: Looks quite clean to me. You may be able to make it shorter, but I don't think you can make it any easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split it once, then slice it:

```
s = 'a.b.c.d'

items = s.split('.')
print [items[:i] for i in xrange(1, len(items) + 1)]
# [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: What about the rest of the loop body in his example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3 then you should use [itertools.accumulate](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) like this:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> txt = 'a.b.c.d'
>>> list( accumulate(txt.split('.'), lambda x,y: x + '.' + y) )
['a', 'a.b', 'a.b.c', 'a.b.c.d']
>>> def example(txt):
    for module in accumulate(txt.split('.'), lambda x,y: x + '.' + y):
        print('Done stuff with %r' % module)

>>> example('a.b.c.d')
Done stuff with 'a'
Done stuff with 'a.b'
Done stuff with 'a.b.c'
Done stuff with 'a.b.c.d'
>>>
```